# To run batch jobs one after the other

Tags: axapta, x++

I submitting jobs to the batch process one after the other.

How do i control such that the second batch job runs only when the first one is finished.

Right now both the jobs executes simultaneously which i dont want to happen

Answer (score 3):

There are two options.  You can do this through code, or just via manual setup.  Manual method is fairly easy, just go to (Basic>Inquiries>Batch Job), create a new batch job and save it.  Then click "View Tasks" and create a new task, where this will be your first batch task.  Choose your class, **description**, batch group, etc., then save.  Click "parameters" to setup the parameters.

After that, you can setup your dependent task.  Make sure your tasks both have descriptions.  Add your second batch task and save.  Then in the lower left corner, you click on your task that you want to have a condition, then add a row there and setup your conditions so that one task won't go until the second has completed.

Via X++ code, you would create a [BatchHeader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc576259%28v=ax.50%29.aspx) where you setup basically the same thing we just did manually.  You use the .addDependency to make one task dependent on the completion of the other.  [This walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc636647.aspx) will get you started with a job to create the batch header, and you'll just have to play around to get the dependency working.

Comment: The above might apply when we 2different tasks for same batch job . But what i am asking is 2 different batch job ....

Comment: Batch jobs should be interdependent unless grouped as described in the answer. So the answer to you comment: make the 2 jobs 2 task in the same job.

Comment: Tejashree S: You may be getting confused on your terminology.  Most things you run in batch are really tasks, and if you run 1 task in 1 job, it's a batch job running 1 task.  A batch job is really just a collection of tasks, which are what actually do work.  So if you want to combine separate batch tasks into one batch job, where each task is dependent on the other, then use my method.  Batch jobs are more ideas used to group processes together.